# Help identifying SMD on USB Circuit (Wacom Intuos 5 - PTH850)

Tags: identification, surface-mount, repair

My Wacom Intuos 5 - PTH850 Tablet have one the following SMDs (the lower one, USB Data -) cracked.

[image: Identifying SMD]
[image: Identifying SMD]

Could you help me identifying which component is? I know each component bridges USB data + with ground (upper one) and USB data - with ground (lower one). None of them have any code (or at least I can't see any).

I will try to get a better picture asap.

FCC ID: https://fccid.io/HV4PTH850

Comment: Either pull down resistors, or inductors/chokes.

Comment: @Passerby Thanks for the help, any idea how can I distinguish them with a multimeter? I might desolder the good one and test it. However I don't know what to test for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are some TVS (transient voltage suppressor) elements. Before going for identification and replacement, you need to check for port functionality first. If one is cracked, just remove it and test the port. Or better remove both TVS. The suppressors are needed to protect against ESD, and don't affect USB functionality at normal signal levels, so the USB should work without them.

If the port is working, you are lucky, and you can try to find the replacement. If the USB port doesn't work after removal of suppressors, your USB lines are likely fried internally, and the whole tablet's board needs replacement if you need the USB functionality.